# Company registration for Small business

Tags: taxes, india, small-business

I am doing trading of goods and also provide services to various organisation. The companies would like to have all future payments made to an organization to which I am proprietor and not directly to my saving account.

As my yearly inward is not more than 2 lacs please suggest the measures to be taken and under which law I can open the organisation.

Comment: No idea about India, but here in the US the simplest solution is to go to our local Town Hall and file a "Doing Business As" form, which registers us as owning that company name. Then we can take that form to a bank and open an account for the company, which lets us accept checks made out to the company. There are reasons why that isn't always sufficient, but for small sole-propriator businesses with minimal liability it's often good enough to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

Sole Proprietor can be registered under the "Shop & Establishment Act". Find out where one can register it in your city. One needs to fill a simple form. Its a nominal fee of Rs 100/-. If there is a Chamber of Commerce, they generally help in completing the formalities for free. A CA can also help you get this done for a small fee.